# Ajuda tables python27

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Bom Dia, sou novo com Python/Tkinter e estou com alguns projetos em mente, porem todos eles tem uso de tabelas junto a eles, alguém poderia me dizer se a alguma biblioteca que eu poderia usar para a criação destas tabelas ou alguma forma de cria-las? já tentei usar o tkintertable mas não achei tutoriais sobre ele, não sei se foi falta de procurar mais :/ , e tentei também o uso do Tktable mas este e para Python3.x, e uso o Python27, agradeço desde já pela atenção!
Ex:
[image: ex:]

Comment: Quando você diz "tabelas" você quer dizer elementos de interface gráfica que representem tabelas, certo? (ex.: planilha, datagrid...) E você está utilizando Tkinter no seu sistema, né? É bom adicionar esses detalhes na pergunta, porque da forma como está ficou meio vago... (numa primeira leitura achei que eram tabelas de banco de dados)

Comment: Bom Dia meu caro amigo, desculpe por ter deixado uma pergunta tao vaga, mas não me refiro a tabelas de bancos de dados não e sim a, tabelas de planilhas tipo as do Excel entende?, quero o seguinte fazer uma pesquisa no banco de dados e ter um retorno nessas tabelas.
ex:
|produto  |ncm    |ean   |
|arroz    |1245565|154487|
putz sou péssimo com esse editor lol mas a tabela arroz deve ficar em baixo da tabela produtos!

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos! Por enquanto, não tenho uma resposta pra te dar, mas mais tarde vou dar uma pesquisada e retorno a essa pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado, espero que de para se fazer algo pois falta apenas este problema a resolver para que eu possa terminar o meu projeto ^^!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizar um Treeview serviria para você? Ele não é editável como um DataGrid, mas você pode alcançar isso de outras maneiras.

[image: Tabela utilizando ttk.Treeview]

Esse código é **amplamente** baseado no post [Tkinter Multi-Column List Demo](http://pyinmyeye.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/tkinter-multi-column-list-demo.html) (sugiro uma visita):

```py
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.set_widgets()

    def set_widgets(self):
        # Inicia o Treeview com as seguintes colunas:
        self.dataCols = ('country', 'capital', 'currency')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=self.dataCols, show='headings')
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.W + tk.E)

        # Barras de rolagem
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree['yscroll'] = ysb.set
        self.tree['xscroll'] = xsb.set
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S)
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E + tk.W)

        # Define o textos do cabeçalho (nome em maiúsculas)
        for c in self.dataCols:
            self.tree.heading(c, text=c.title())

        # Dados:
        self.data = [
            ("Argentina",      "Buenos Aires",     "ARS"),
            ("Australia",      "Canberra",         "AUD"),
            ("Brazil",         "Brazilia",         "BRL"),
            ("Canada",         "Ottawa",           "CAD"),
            ("China",          "Beijing",          "CNY"),
            ("France",         "Paris",            "EUR"),
            ("Germany",        "Berlin",           "EUR"),
            ("India",          "New Delhi",        "INR"),
            ("Italy",          "Rome",             "EUR"),
            ("Japan",          "Tokyo",            "JPY"),
            ("Mexico",         "Mexico City",      "MXN"),
            ("Russia",         "Moscow",           "RUB"),
            ("South Africa",   "Pretoria",         "ZAR"),
            ("United Kingdom", "London",           "GBP"),
            ("United States",  "Washington, D.C.", "USD"),
        ]

        # Insere cada item dos dados
        for item in self.data:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```